# AWS SQS Maven Dependency Throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : software/amazon/awssdk/services/sqs/SqsClient On Runtime

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I am getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : software/amazon/awssdk/services/sqs/SqsClient` when I am trying to download the AWS SDK for SQS from a Maven dependency

My Dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqs</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I get the error when I try to run this line of code:

```
SqsClient sqsClient = SqsClient.builder().region(Region.US_WEST_2).build();
```

and I am importing `import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.SqsClient` which is compiling fine on VSCode and Netbeans, but failing at runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

I did a `mvn clean install` and on VSCode, I did a Run Without Debugging instead of just clicking up on my terminal.